# bootstrap - modal close button not closing

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap 4 and I added a modal in my form in laravel project.

Code:

```
........

    <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                  <button type="button" id="order-btn" class="btn btn-yellow-hub rounded-pill px-30">Procced</button>
               </div>
           </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>


 <!-- Modal -->
 <div class="modal fade" id="confirmOrder" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content modal-content-height">
        <div class="modal-header" style="background-color: #D0D0D0">
          <h5 class="modal-title">Order Confirmation</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Your credit balance will be charge RM{{$rate->cost}} for the invoice. Proceed this order?</p>
          <div class="text-center">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary confirm-pay-now ">Pay Now</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Basically, the data dismiss for close button is not working and nothing happens when I clicked it. I checked the bootstrap documentation and everything seems to be in order. Some of the solutions I have tried is removing `fade` class which does nothing. I also tried adding  `$('#closeButtonID').modal('hide');` but it does not seem to work as well.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure If you use CDN then check you your internet connectivity or you use local library then try to go at view page source check that you local library correctly integrate with you webpage..
2. or I think you need to go through with below reference link try it
   https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
$('#confirmOrder').modal('hide');
```

instead of

```
$('#closeButtonID').modal('hide');
```

Can you try giving it to the event handler of the button click as

```
$('. btn-secondary').on('click', function() {
    $('#confirmOrder').modal('hide');
})
```

Comment: The data dismiss does not work is it because there is an event propagation somewhere?

Comment: Nop, the button is directly given to under the modal right, we will check that. but instead is the hide working ?

Comment: Can you post the full code where to place it.

Comment: On button click, can you write and event handler and write this code under the same fnction

Comment: like this: ``` $('#closeModalBtn').click(function () {
                $('#confirmOrder').modal('hide');
            });```

Comment: I will update in answer, `closeModalBtn` you have not given to the html yet

Comment: So, now the data-dismiss issue is the one that exists right ?

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                  <button type="button" id="order-btn" class="btn btn-yellow-hub rounded-pill px-30" data-target="#confirmOrder" data-toggle="modal">Procced</button>
               </div>
           </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>


 <!-- Modal -->
 <div class="modal fade" id="confirmOrder" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content modal-content-height">
        <div class="modal-header" style="background-color: #D0D0D0">
          <h5 class="modal-title">Order Confirmation</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Your credit balance will be charge RM{{$rate->cost}} for the invoice. Proceed this order?</p>
          <div class="text-center">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary confirm-pay-now ">Pay Now</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```